# TypeError: Array not defined

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet that checks up every row in a table, and if a given row has specific content in one of its cells, it checks the checkbox in that row. However I always end up with a message:

```
[19:55:11.752] TypeError: rows[a] is undefined
```

The full code for my bookmarklet:

```
document.getElementsByName('0.0.7.3.0.9.3.1.1.1.0.13.3.1.1.11.1.3'[0].options[2].selected=true;
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('content-status')[0];
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var a=1; a<=rows.length; a++){
    if(rows[a].getElementsByClassName('pricing-tiers')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML != 'Invalid Price') {
        rows[a].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked=true;
    }
}
document.getElementsByName('0.0.7.3.0.9.3.1.1.1.0.21.2.0.1.1.1')[0].click();
```

I intentionally start a from 1 since 0rd row is a header row.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So are you sure you're getting anything in `rows`?  Do a console.log() of it before you do your `for` loop and I'm sure you'll see the problem.  @canon His code didn't even reach that point.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica There's an error in his very first line. That's what I was pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is jumping one element too far because of the `<=`:

```
for(var a=1; a<=rows.length; a++){
              ^^
```

Change it to a `<` and it'll work.

Comment: God dammit. It's always that ONE character that your brain cannot see. Thank you SO much!